# Error handling in Knockout AMD Helpers

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-amd-helpers

I'm using the Knockout AMD helpers project which is nice as I can modularize my knockout modules much better.

My problem is that it seems to totally hide errors. This is not so much of a problem in a small project but as the project grows then it would be helpful if errors were visible in the console.

So I've just had a situation:

```
<div data-bind="click: doStuff">
    <!-- Lots of other html -->
</div>
```

If the function doStuff does not exist the entire module will not work. Obviously once the error is known it's an easy fix but identifying this error does not seem easy atall as Knockout does not log this to the console.

Basically if this project is to be used for production systems by a team of developers I would expect it to report binding errors somehow.

Am I missing something here?

Thanks

Comment: What version of Knockout are you using?  Any binding errors should show up in the console. I just did some quick testing with AMD helpers and they are not swallowed/hidden. Would like to understand your setup a bit better to see how I can help you with this issue.

Comment: Using Knockout JavaScript library v3.4.0. I think I'll create a fiddle to show what I mean.

Comment: Sounds good. I'll keep an eye out for your fiddle.